# What do my scores from Duolingo's Test Center mean?

Tags: duolingo

I just took an English proficiency test from Duolingo (I'm German) and I scored a 76%. I need to know what the average score is, as well as a basic idea of what each score range means I "should" be able to do. If I got a 76%, what "should" I be able to do? Speak English well enough to have a short conversation? Or should I be able to write essays in English?

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning! I'm not exactly sure how this is related to language learning, so could you please edit your question to perhaps make it more on-topic?

Comment: This is about software operation, not language learning.

Comment: @user3169: It's about using software for language learning. When this topic came up pre-beta, [we decided](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/21523/39315) to answer such questions, as long as they relate specifically to language learning. If you feel a different decision should be made, please bring it up on [meta](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Flimzy As shown in the accepted answer, it is about the interpretation of a software scoring system, the validity of which has not been independently established. Words like "average" and "can" don't help.

Comment: @user3169: I'm not sure what point you're making. The question is one that language learners are likely to have, and it is related to their task as language learners, so the question ought to be on-topic. If the answer is unsatisfying, that just means the software is poorly defined/described (which should be absolutely no surprise WRT Duolingo), not that the question is off-topic.

Comment: @user3169: In any case, as I said before, if you feel this class of question ought to be closed, you should make your case on meta, not here in comments.

Answer (score 8):

That's very coincidental because I just took my Duolingo test last week. I used [Duolingo's official page](https://testcenter.duolingo.com/scores) on this topic for help.

I've summarised the table here but if you want the full version you can visit the link above.

- 0 - 16% is beginner. Can only understand very basic words or phrases
  in the language.
- 17% - 35% is elementary. Can deal with simple, straightforward
  information and express themselves in familiar contexts.
- 36% - 55% is intermediate. Can understand the main points of concrete
  speech or writing on routine matters such as work and school. Can
  handle most situations that would come up while traveling where the
  language is spoken. Can describe experiences, ambitions, opinions,
  and plans, although with some awkwardness or hesitation.
- 56% - 71% is advanced. Can fulfill most communication goals, even on
  unfamiliar topics. Can understand the main ideas of both concrete and
  abstract writing, and interact with native speakers fairly
  painlessly.
- 72% - 92% is proficient. Can understand a variety of demanding texts
  and conversations, also grasping implicit or figurative meaning that
  is hidden. Can use language flexibly and effectively for most social,
  academic, and professional purposes.
- 93% - 100% is expert. Can understand virtually anything heard or
  read, even intellectually demanding material such as an academic
  lecture or a book on philosophy. Can use the language fluently and
  spontaneously in a way that can even be more advanced than an average
  native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I took Duolingo's test as well, I think 50 marks is average. Above 80% means that you are exceptionally proficient in the English language. I received 80 marks.

Comment: I appreciate your answer!